# Populating select option with ajax (in php)

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to make a search form in which an user types an user's name and, while typing, a select tag is populated with data from DB (data such as id, first name, last name and picture). I'm sure you all know the search button from Linkedin, that is exactly what I need.
I know it's complicated, if you know where to take an example from, that would be enough.
Thanks.

Comment: it's not so complicated as you'd think.. try this [tutorial](http://ninetofive.me/blog/build-a-live-search-with-ajax-php-and-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/

Is a excellent script to do this.